# Conditional print in Angularjs and Bootstrap LESS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a conditional print requirement in Angular and Bootstrap environment. The requirement is to print a div when the condition exists.

On the HTML code:

```
<div class="print" ng-show="objects[0].exists">
   ///My print Part

 </div>
```

On the LESS code:

```
 >.print{
      .visible-print-block; 
 }
```

What's happening in my case is `.visible-print-block` is overriding the Angular condition and printing the div irrespectively of the condition.

Comment: I used two ng-if statements, <div ng-if="objects[0].exists"> and <div ng-if="!objects[0].exists">. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **ng-class directive**

So your coude would look like:

```
<div ng-class= '{"print": objects[0].exists}'>
   ///My print Part

 </div>
```

Using this solution the class 'print' will only be applied if  the result of objects[0].exists is true.

Comment: Tried this but, had no luck.